# android toolbar why do i get options menu instead of icons

Tags: android

so i made my own toolbar with a menu and i am infalting it:

```
toolbarBottom.inflateMenu (R.menu.user_interaction);
```

and this is the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item app:title="Edit"
        app:id="@+id/post"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pinboard_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />
    <item app:id="@+id/menu_share"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recent_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:title="Undo" />
    <item app:id="@+id/test"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_groups_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:title="Redo" />
</menu>
```

what i get now is the 3 android option dots on the right side of my bar. If i press it my 3 menu´s appear. What i want is the 3 menu items to appear on the bar itself witht he 3 icon drawables.

Where is my mistake? Did i forgot something? :O

Comment: Have you tried to write android: instead of app:? (for example, android:icon instead of app:icon)

Comment: yup that worked. now i have another problem...the icons are at the right side of it.. is there a way to make them equaly spread over the bar? Smth like layout_weight for buttons?

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:title="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pinboard_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recent_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Undo" />
    <item android:id="@+id/test"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_groups_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Redo" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:title="Edit"
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pinboard_white"
    app:showAsAction="always"

    />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recent_white"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Undo" />
<item android:id="@+id/test"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_groups_white"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Redo" />
</menu>
```